# Automatic Update all posts at once

Tags: wordpress

I made some changes in a plugin that creates meta boxes, i added tome default code into the "value" of the meta box. 
The data is being sent outside. my problem is that now i need to press "update" on every woocommerce product for it to be permanently saved and sent. But i have 1500 products.

I have tried bulk updating from the general admin area, like Shawn here:
https://bobwp.com/bulk-edit-posts-wordpress/

It didn't work. so i tried this code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'post_type' => 'product'
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $casa_id = $post->ID;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'casa_id', $casa_id);
    }
}
```

And also this:

```
function woo_zap_update_product_name() {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    $zap_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    if ( $zap_query->have_posts() ) {

        global $post;

        while ( $zap_query->have_posts() ) {
            $zap_query->the_post();
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wc_zap_product_name', $post->post_title );
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'woo_zap_update_product_name' );
```

Didn't work as well.. any other ideas ?

Comment: What is the name of the meta box field and which data has to be store on this field ?

Comment: this is the plugin: https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-zap-mirror/. it creates a XML sitemap for some israeli shopping website to read. it has several values... in short - when i press "update" manually it's all good. i need to find a way to do that automatically for all the 1500 products.

Comment: We may need a little more info -- when you say neither of those didn't work, what exactly happened? Did it just refresh with no change to the data?

Comment: yes... refresh with no change at all